# Mongoose aggregation not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Mongodb 2.2.0 and [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) 3.3.1.

I am trying to run [aggregate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-aggregate) on the following query:

```
var db = mongoose.connect('localhost', 'test', '27017').connection;
var testSchema = new Schema;
var tr= db.model('tests', testSchema);  

tr.aggregate({'$group':{'_id':'$test_id', 'average':{$avg:'$tes_tscore'}}})
```

The following error keeps popping up:

```
TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
    if (!(this instanceof model))
      return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
    Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
  } has no method 'aggregate'
```

Does mongoose not support aggregation just yet or is my code missing something?

** The `tests` collection has over 1000 documents.  Running `tr.find(... console.log(...)` returns the desired documents.

Comment: you can aggregate without using the aggregate helper by using db.runCommand("aggregate":collectionName, "pipeline":<your pipeline>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

putting `console.log(mongoose.version);` in the script showed up as outdated version (3.0.2).

I went back through the modules (carefully this time) and deleted and re-installed `mongoose`.
Version 3.3.1 and `aggregate` now works.

`aggregate` came online v.3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

aggregate is supported in 3.x. the code in your example looks ok but somehow `tr` refers to the model() method instead of a model instance. if you are able to consistently recreate this issue, please open a ticket with the exact code to run and we'll get it fixed.

https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/new

Comment: I can consistently recreate this issue.  Not only with this model but with others as well.  I'll submit a ticket.